# jQuery Menu List To Breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, jquery

### My jQuery Breadcrumb

```
Breadcrumb = $(e.target).parentsUntil(".Menu").filter("li").children("a").map(function() {
                 return $(this).html().trim().replace(/Master Dashboard/g,"Dashboard");
             }).get().reverse().join("<li><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-right\"></i></li>");
```

---

### Returns

```
<i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
<span class="Title">Account</span>
<span class="Arrow"></span>

<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></li>

<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
<span class="Title">Messages</span>
<span class="Arrow"></span>

<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></li>

<i class="fa fa-inbox fa-lg"></i>
<span class="Title">Inbox</span>
<span class="Counter">1,234</span>
```

---

### Needs To Be

```
<li>
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
    <span class="Title">Account</span>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></li>
<li>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
    <span class="Title">Messages</span>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></li>
<li>
    <i class="fa fa-inbox fa-lg"></i>
    <span class="Title">Inbox</span>
</li>
```

---

### Question

I've tried several ways to `.wrap("<li></li>")` and to remove unwanted `<span>...</span>`'s from my breadcrumb however all have resulted in breaking my script.

How do I achieve my 'Needs To Be' by:

1. Remove all `span.Arrow` and `span.Counter`
2. Wrap each section in `<li></li>`

---

### Live Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 "use strict";
 
 $(document).on('click', function(e) {
  var Breadcrumb;
  if ($(e.target).closest($('.Menu')).length) {
 
   Breadcrumb = $(e.target).parentsUntil(".Menu").filter("li").children("a").map(function() {
       return $(this).html().trim().replace(/Master Dashboard/g,"Dashboard");
       }).get().reverse().join("<li><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-right\"></i></li>");
   
   console.log(Breadcrumb);
  };
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SideNav">
 <!-- === Navigation Menu Starts === -->
 <ul class="Menu">

  <!-- === Minified Nav Starts === -->
  <li class="MinifySideBar" style="display: none;">
   <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Master-Dashboard">
    <i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-2x"></i>
   </a>
  </li>
  <!-- === Minified Nav Ends === -->

  <!-- === Main Dashboard Starts === -->
  <li>
   <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Master-Dashboard">
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
    <span class="Title">Master Dashboard</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <!-- === Main Dashboard Ends === -->

  <!-- === User Account Starts === -->
  <li>
   <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
    <span class="Title">Account</span>
    <span class="Arrow"></span>
   </a>
   <ul class="sub-menu First">

    <!-- === User Account Dashboard Starts === -->
    <li>
     <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Dashboard">
      <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="Title">Dashboard</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <!-- === User Account Dashboard Ends === -->

    <!-- === User Messages Starts === -->
    <li>
     <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="Title">Messages</span>
      <span class="Arrow"></span>
     </a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Compose">
        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="Title">Compose</span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Inbox">
        <i class="fa fa-inbox fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="Title">Inbox</span>
        <span class="Counter">1,234</span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Drafts">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="Title">Drafts</span>
        <span class="Counter">123</span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Trash">
        <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="Title">Trash</span>
        <span class="Counter">12</span>
       </a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- === User Messages Ends === -->
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: post the contents of e.target

Comment: Click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: also, just using jQuery `remove()` you can already fix the first point

Comment: @LordNeo I've tried `.remove()` in several places so far, however I cannot seem to figure out how to do so prior appending to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE with document click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 "use strict";
 
 $(document).on('click', function(e) {
  var Breadcrumb;
  if ($(e.target).closest($('.Menu')).length) {
 
   Breadcrumb = $(e.target).parentsUntil(".Menu").find('li a').map(function() {
 var el = $(this); // remove second span
 $(el).find('span.Counter,span.Arrow,i').remove();
 $(el).prepend("<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-right\"></i>");
 var tx = $(el).html().replace(/Master Dashboard/g,"Dashboard").replace(/\t/g, "")
 var out = "<li>" + tx + "</li>";
 return out;
}).get().reverse();
   
   console.log(Breadcrumb);
  };
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="SideNav">
 <!-- === Navigation Menu Starts === -->
 <ul class="Menu">

  <!-- === Minified Nav Starts === -->
  <li class="MinifySideBar" style="display: none;">
   <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Master-Dashboard">
    <i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-2x"></i>
   </a>
  </li>
  <!-- === Minified Nav Ends === -->

  <!-- === Main Dashboard Starts === -->
  <li>
   <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Master-Dashboard">
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
    <span class="Title">Master Dashboard</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <!-- === Main Dashboard Ends === -->

  <!-- === User Account Starts === -->
  <li>
   <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
    <span class="Title">Account</span>
    <span class="Arrow"></span>
   </a>
   <ul class="sub-menu First">

    <!-- === User Account Dashboard Starts === -->
    <li>
     <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Dashboard">
      <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="Title">Dashboard</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <!-- === User Account Dashboard Ends === -->

    <!-- === User Messages Starts === -->
    <li>
     <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="Title">Messages</span>
      <span class="Arrow"></span>
     </a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Compose">
        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="Title">Compose</span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Inbox">
        <i class="fa fa-inbox fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="Title">Inbox</span>
        <span class="Counter">1,234</span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Drafts">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="Title">Drafts</span>
        <span class="Counter">123</span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Account/Messages/Trash">
        <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
        <span class="Title">Trash</span>
        <span class="Counter">12</span>
       </a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- === User Messages Ends === -->
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

this one outputs correct html for you:

see if it's ok now, cheers k

Comment: **First:** `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html(...).trim(...).replace(...).wrap is not a function`, **Second:** `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html(...).trim(...).replace(...).join is not a function`

Comment: Now I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined` and breaks my menu. You can see my live version [here](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/index.html)

Comment: can you paste full html that is wrapping your menu so I can test it @my end?

Comment: `<div class="SideNav"><ul class="Menu"> /** List Items **/ </ul></div>` or do you need more than this? There is [my live version](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/index.html) or I can edit my question?

Comment: Please edit your question and create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor. Also why parentsuntil?

Comment: Updated my question with live example

Comment: It all needs to be done via `e,target` as the menu will not be there on page load. It is designed just for the current path, alike you see when you click on a menu item on my demo above, reversed to show a breadcrumb.

Comment: hey @TimMarshall see if that's better now

Comment: Hiya @oserk I seen your update. It's looking better however it's a breadcrumb so if you click on `Compose` it should return `Dashboard > Account > Messages > Compose`

Comment: yeah Tim, I understand you but it's a separate question now, your original was to fix the html output for your needs which I think I did and is working now, correct?

Comment: No, I started off with a script which worked however I wanted elements to be wrapped and elements removed. Your script may solve the wrapping and removal of elements however has drifted from my original script and if I accepted this as an answer, I would then have to create a new question to implement what you've done to result in what I have done.

Comment: Bare with me one moment, I think I may have fixed it

Comment: that's right, create new question with my logic for removing and wrapping stuff, and ask to go recursively up to to root for custom breadcrumb logic

Comment: See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89rh2yjp/) in your code above, change `Breadcrumb = $(e.target).parentsUntil(".Menu").find('li a').map(function() {` to `Breadcrumb = $(e.target).parentsUntil(".Menu").filter("li").children("a").map(function() {`

Comment: great @TimMarshall I have changed that filter thing didn't thought would metter,, now it's working as expected?

Comment: Indeed it is! I've just got some minor tweaking to do and should be done! :)